# Should we import BrowserModule in all modules created inside an Angular app?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes, angular-cli

I'm new in Angular. I got the explanation for `BrowserModule` as follows.

> Exports required infrastructure for all Angular apps. Included by
>   default in all Angular apps created with the CLI new command.
>   Re-exports CommonModule and ApplicationModule, making their exports
>   and providers available to all apps.

I found this `BrowserModule` being imported in an app module by default, when I used angular-cli.

My doubt is, should we import `BrowserModule` in all modules created inside an Angular app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root application module, AppModule, of almost every browser application should import `BrowserModule` from `@angular/platform-browser.`

> BrowserModule provides services that are essential to launch and run
>   a browser app.

`BrowserModule` also re-exports CommonModule from `@angular/common`, which means that components in the `AppModule` module also have access to the Angular directives every app needs, such as `NgIf` and `NgFor`.

**Do not import `BrowserModule` in any other module. Feature modules and lazy-loaded modules should import CommonModule instead.** They need common directives. They don't need to re-install the app-wide providers.

[**Official Documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-import-browsermodule-or-commonmodule)

Answer (score 1):

> The root application module, AppModule, of almost every browser
>   application should import BrowserModule from
>   @angular/platform-browser.
>
> BrowserModule provides services that are essential to launch and run a
>   browser app.
>
> BrowserModule also re-exports CommonModule from @angular/common, which
>   means that components in the AppModule module also have access to the
>   Angular directives every app needs, such as NgIf and NgFor.
>
> Do not import BrowserModule in any other module. Feature modules and
>   lazy-loaded modules should import CommonModule instead. They need the
>   common directives. They don't need to re-install the app-wide
>   providers.

Check Reference [Here](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-import-browsermodule-or-commonmodule)

Answer (score 0):

`BrowserModule` provides services that are essential to **launch and run a browser app**. Do not import `BrowserModule` in any other module that you create. As you mentioned, it's automatically imported into the root application module, **AppModule** by CLI.

Go through this [link](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-import-browsermodule-or-commonmodule) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserModule is required by default by any new web based angular application.
It should be imported from @angular/platform-browser.

BrowserModule also re-exports CommonModule from @angular/common, which means that components in the AppModule module also have access to the Angular directives every app needs, such as NgIf and NgFor.